# Magento Model- calling load memory overflow

Tags: php, magento, memory-management

I am very new to Magento and just learning about Models. I am trying to follow Alan Storms tutorial, and have created my Model. However, the following code causes a memory overflow error:

`Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php on line 447`

My `IndexController.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
  class Lock_Weblog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function testModelAction() {
      $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
      $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
      echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
      $blogpost->load(1);    
      //$data = $blogpost->getData();
      //var_dump($data); 
    }
  }
?>
```

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<config>      
  <global>
    <modules>
      <Lock_Weblog>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </Lock_Weblog>
    </modules>
    <models>
      <weblog>
        <class>Lock_Weblog_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>weblog_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </weblog>
      <weblog_mysql4>
        <class>Lock_Weblog_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
          <blogpost>
            <table>blog_posts</table>
          </blogpost>
        </entities>
      </weblog_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <weblog_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </weblog_write>
      <weblog_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </weblog_read>
    </resources>
  </global> 
  <frontend>
      <routers>
          <weblog>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                  <module>Lock_Weblog</module>
                  <frontName>weblog</frontName>
              </args>
          </weblog>
      </routers>
  </frontend> 
</config>
```

I am completely lost as to what to do to fix this!
Any help appreciated

Comment: What is your server configuration.

Comment: What part of my server configuration are you interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Magento needs `256M` (`512M` is best) `memory_limit` to run the website properly.

You only have `64M`. Increase the limit in your php.ini and everything should work fine.

Comment: Hi. I should have mentioned- I have the same problem even when I increase the  memory to 512 (obviously it takes longer before it overflows). I just changed it to a lower amount for testing.

Comment: @Lock post your whole code.. may be you Mage::logged some object in Model file which can take whole memory space?